# are automatically generated primary keys in H2 database always positive?

Tags: sql, h2

Can I assume that the automatically generated primary keys in H2 database are always positive?

Comment: Why? It is a *surrogate key* with the sole purpose of optimizing specific joins because of the width of the natural (primary) key. Don't muddy the waters of your logical data model by attaching a logical attribute to this property that exists solely in the physical model. Besides, that new column breaks First Normal Form for the table by being a *repeating group*.

Comment: P.S. Recall that once a table breaks First Normal Form, one no longer has a *relational table* - storage in an RDBMS not withstanding.

Comment: Yes you can assume that they will always be positive.  What Pieter may have been driving at is that it doesn't matter whether they are positive or negative as long at they are unique.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, after reading the source code, I realized that the default behavior is to start sequences from 1 (so no negative number will be generated)

Answer (score 1):

Researching in the source code of H2, shows that the following SQL statement

```
create sequence some_name;
```

will generate a sequence from the default start value which is 1. ([see source](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/278e6e8172db9ff393afec415cebe5fbb719ce65/h2/src/main/org/h2/schema/Sequence.java))
It is however possible to have another start value, [more info here](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_sequence)

Comment: Even if they were negative, what difference does it make? A primary key only needs to be **unique** the actual value of the number does not matter at all.

Comment: Yes it should be unique, but I want to show this ID to the users in my program and having negative IDs does not look pleasing to eyes. So I wanted to make sure that they will be positive. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: **Never** show generated ids to the user. And having to avoid negative numbers just for that is only one reason.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name isn't a generated key what an account number is?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: no, not at all. A generated key, is only a unique number. Nothing more. It has no meaning and the actual value is not important. The only thing that a generated key needs to be is unique.